# How to shorten the same part in jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

If I have a if/else statement:

```
if(a) {         
  $('#aa').removeClass('Offselect').addClass('Onselect').css('background-image','url(../images/menu.gif)');
} 
else if(b) { 
  $('#bb').removeClass('Offselect').addClass('Onselect').css('background-image','url(../images/menu.gif)');
} 
else if(c) { 
  $('#cc').removeClass('Offselect').addClass('Onselect').css('background-image','url(../images/menu.gif)');
} 
else if(d) { 
 //same part
}
```

You can see the code have the same part:

```
removeClass('Offselect').addClass('Onselect').css('background-image','url(../images/menu.gif)');
```

Is it possible or any suggestion to shorten the same code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/apcL045s/1/

Comment: can you tell us what `if(a)` is actually checking? Is it true/false or looking for an actual value in your real code?

Answer (score 2):

Use **function** to reused code :

```
if(a) {  
 // pass jquery selector as a reference       
 doProcess( $('#aa') );
} 
else if(b) { 
  doProcess( $('#bb') );
} 
else if(c) { 
  doProcess( $('#cc') );
} 
else if(d) { 
 //same part
}


function doProcess( e ){
  // use e as selector
  e.removeClass('Offselect').addClass('Onselect').css('background-image','url(../images/menu.gif)');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new function to perform all of that. Something like this:

```
var myFunction = function (jqObject) {
    jqObject.removeClass('Offselect').addClass('Onselect').css('background-image','url(../images/menu.gif)');
}
```

and then use it like so:

```
if(a) {         
    myFunction($('#aa'));
} 
else if (b) {
    myFunction($('#bb'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `if` statements are checking for specific values in your actual code, I'd create an object mapping the possible values to element ids like `var elements={'a':"#aa","b":"#bb","c":"#cc"};` then pass your value to a function that will find the mapped element and apply the changes, something like the below (css added for demo purposes)

```js
function modifyElement(key){
    var elements={'a':"#aa","b":"#bb","c":"#cc"};
    $(elements[key]).removeClass('Offselect').addClass('Onselect').css('background-image','url(https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=14&txt=50x100&w=100&h=50)');
}
modifyElement('a');
```

```css
div{
    background-color:green;
    width:50px;
    min-height:10px;
}
.Offselect{
    height:50px;
}
.Onselect{
    width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aa" class="Offselect"></div><br>
<div id="bb" class="Offselect"></div><br>
<div id="cc" class="Offselect"></div><br>
```